# Check if all values of array are equal to number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to see if there is a better way to check if all values of array are equal to number. I have it working with a foreach but wanted to see if I can do this anyway else?

```
let valid = true;
$.each(data.resultStatus, function (index, resultStatus) {
    if (resultStatus.ResultCode == "2") {
        valid = false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: How would I use every() would it be `data.resultStatus.every((element.ResultCode, index) => 1`

Comment: Please read the docs. Or [edit] your question to show a [mre] and an error your receiving. Looks like you'll need something like: `data.resultStatus.every(e => e == 2);`

Comment: `data.resultStatus.every(e => e.ResultCode == "2")`

Comment: Shouldn't the condition in your function be `!=`?

Comment: You are correct it need to be `!=2`